# Git: how to ensure all dev's working branches have a required change?

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control, continuous-integration

With other source control systems I've used, there was always a way to ensure that if some global change that was required for builds to work or unit tests to run it would be immediately available to all developers. But with git, if each developer is working on a separate branch inside their own repository, it's not clear how to achieve this. For instance, just yesterday I had to make a change to a unit test that was failing now that it was no longer 2016, but every developer who pushed commits to their own branches kept getting ci build failures because they hadn't pulled and merged from the master branch with the fix. We also often have to change build scripts because of build server and network configuration changes, but again, there seems to be no obvious way to automatically "push" these changes out to all developers so their branches will build successfully. Are there any good/known solutions for this sort of problem? Surely it's not just us...

Comment: honestly developers should know to merge with the stable (or master) branch on a periodic basis.. they should do it every day..

Comment: "periodic" isn't good enough - these are changes that are needed immediately because of some external change. And there are other times when you're working on a significant refactoring where merging *everything* from the master branch is not feasible.  Also, merging everything from 'master' makes it harder to apply your fixes to other stable branches.

Comment: merging from the master branch should always be feasible.. I've never had an issue where it wasn't even when working on significant refactoring.  If I were you I would look at the pre push hook.. with this, before they push you can merge whatever changes that are needed into their branch

Comment: @DylanNicholson, have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: The answers I've seen so far only seem to serve my feeling that git's missing this functionality in the way I'd hope it might work.

Comment: @DylanNicholson, not exactly, developers should merge their local branches to master, and then push master branch to remote. CI build/test for master branch make sense not every developer’s local branches.  And I updated my answer (highlight the step to merge before push) and this is the common way.

Comment: I think the answer is the rebase on master. When working on a feature branch, run `git pull --rebase origin master` to get the latest changes from the server's master branch into your local branch. Most git server tooling allow you to protect the `master` branch so no one can push to it and only Pull Requests can be merged in. If you run CI on each PR and reject it until tests pass, then `master` will always pass.

Comment: Not sure that would help - but to solve to specific issue we see (where ci builds fail because dev haven't merged the latest changes into their branches) the only option seems to be to modify the ci build script to attempt to perform the merge itself on the build machine before building. Obviously that's still an issue when there are merge conflicts though.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that your build scripts always changed, but it’s not effect git to do the version control.

Your remote repository’s URL is stable that is enough for git.

To make sure the developers work based on the newest master branch, there are two ways:

1. Before push to remote remote, fetch master branch from remote to check if the local works is based on the newest master branch. You can try below steps:

`git fetch origin master
 git diff master..origin/master`

If there has output, that means the local master branch is not the newest. You should rebase your local `branchX` on the top of newest master branch by `git checkout branchX` and git `pull origin master --rebase`.

2. You can also use pre-push hook, so that before push to remote repo, git can detect if it’s based on newest master branch.

**BTW**, what’s the branch module for your team. Developers develop work on their own dev branch and then pushed their works to remote dev branch. But who will merge the changes in dev branch to master branch? If you only have development team (no QA or some), the common way is **every developer should merge his changes to master branch, then push the local master branch to remote**. So that if local master branch is not newest, git will stop push and hint the reason for you. I think it’s the better way if this is your situation.

If you have more team. Such as development, QA etc, there is [a successful git branch module](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for you to refer.

**Update**

No matter CI build or test, all these steps will executed after the developers push their local changes to remote repository. **So the normal methods for develops is merge their local changes to master branch, and then push master branch to remote.** If developers local master branch is not newest, git will automatically stop users to push and hint to pull changes from remote firstly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a git expert, but for that scenario I think there is no automatic option until developers pull the changes. That will update THEIR develop branch and they have to merge the change to their own branch. They have two options for doing that, integrate develop to their branch or cherry-pick specific commit which contains the required change.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there are times when your master has failing tests and times when it does not. So the solution is simple - let's developer start their branches from commits which have passed all tests.

PS: I once read some rant from Linus regarding Linux kernel development - he asked developers to base their patches on a released kernel version, not a random master commit which happened to be current. I think there is a point in this rule.

PS2: if your test outcome depends on current date or there are other reasons that same source code fails even if was passing before it is bad and you should put some efforts so that it does not happen